# Python: REGULAR EXPRESSION on text

Tags: python, regex

Q4:Delete all the reference numbers in the text (including their brackets). It should delete the following:
[8] etc.
Before deleting them, print the list of those reference numbers then print the following:
There are {length of list} references numbers to be deleted. My codes are below:

```
import re
with open('macOS.txt', 'r') as f:
  content = f.read()
  
temp = re.sub('<[^>]*>', '', content)
print(f'There are {len(temp)} references numbers to be deleted.')
print(temp)
```

While I am not sure is this right answer? **For delete [8],[9] I used re.sub('<[^>]*>', '',content)**

Q5:**Using the new text from no.4**, split the text to check how many sentences are in the text. Be careful to not split on the period in something like the following:

> by Apple Inc.

> since 2001 OS X 10.1 etc.

Then print the following:
There are {length of list} sentences in the text.

**But in Q5 I don't know how to use the new text from Q4?** Anyone can please guide me how to do this?

Comment: You can not match `[8]` with `'<[^>]*>`, you could use `\[\d+]` to remove the square brackets that contain 1 or more digits.

Comment: temp = re.sub('\[\d+]', '', content) is this right?

Comment: Please review [homework guidance.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to match 1 or more digits between square brackets, you can use `\[\d+]`.

You can get the number of matches running `len` on the result of re.findall and use re.sub to replace the matches with a space.

```
import re

pattern = r"\[\d+]"

with open('macOS.txt', 'r') as f:
    content = f.read()
    print(f'There are {len(re.findall(pattern, content))} references numbers to be deleted.')
    result = re.sub(pattern, ' ', content)

    # use result for further processing
```

Comment: You are right!! the output is :There are 9 references numbers to be deleted. but do you know how to Use the new text from this code? because I have to split the text to check how many sentences are in the text......

Comment: @ssssmaner This line `re.sub(pattern, ' ', content)` returns the text with the replacements. You could assign that to a variable `result = re.sub(pattern, ' ', content)`

Comment: result = re.sub(pattern, ' ', content)
with open('result', 'r') as f:
  content = f.read()
temp= re.match(r"(.*\.{1}\s{1})[A-Z].*",content)
print(f'There are {len(temp)} sentences in the text.')

Comment: I try to use the codes above but the error shows No such file or directory: 'result'

Comment: @ssssmaner You can not do it like that. The content is what is read from the file, and you can not use it in the pattern before it as it does not exist yet.

Comment: result = re.sub(pattern, ' ', content)
temp= re.match(r"(.*\.{1}\s{1})[A-Z].*",result)
print(f'There are {len(temp)} sentences in the text.'). is this okay?

Comment: findall = re.sub(pattern, ' ', content)

paragraphs = re.split('\n\n+', findall)
splitted_text = [paragraph.split() for paragraph in paragraphs]
print(f'There are {len(splitted_text)} sentences in the text.') this works but not sure it is right or not

Comment: @ssssmaner Splitting on 2 or more newlines `splitted_text` will give you the number of "paragraphs" it that is the logic to get a paragraph. See this example code to count the lines per paragraph https://ideone.com/EIOu08